# Cannot assign to immutable expression of type ' String?'

Tags: ios, swift

Working with text from a table view here. I am running into issues with the second bit of code.

This works:

```
var objects:CKRecord!


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

   Notes.text = objects.objectForKey("content") as? String

}
```

Yet this doesn't work:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    objects.objectForKey("content") as? String = Notes.text // problem line

}
```

Why not?

Comment: Did you notice that there are two related methods: `func objectForKey(_ key: String) -> CKRecordValue?` and `func setObject(_ object CKRecordValue?, forKey key: String)`  ?

Comment: They are two methods I'm using in the same class. One to load data, which is working and one to "save" data on return.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

```
@IBAction func Save(sender: AnyObject) {

   objects["content"] = Notes.text as? String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original attempt does not work because `objects.objectForKey("content") as? String` is an **R-value**: both the `objects.objectForKey(_:)` method and the `as?` operator return read-only values that you cannot assign to.

Your posted solution works because the `[]` operator returns an `inout` value for dictionaries, making `objects["content"]` an **L-value**.

See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue) for an explanation of L-values and R-values.